# If a laptop works with WiFi 802.11ac, does it work with 802.11n?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, laptop

I am looking to purchase a new laptop for my mom. For this question, the relevant requirement is: **it must work with WiFi 802.11n**.

I found a candidate that seems perfect on everything else, but regarding WiFi, **all it says is "WiFi: 802.11ac"**. My knowledge regarding these WiFi standards is very shallow... All I know is that 802.11ac is more recent than 802.11n, but I am afraid that perhaps this candidate works only with 802.11ac, and not 802.11n...

When I bought my smartphone for example, it said explicitly "802.11 a/b/g/n/ac". Unfortunately, this laptop I found is not explicit on this, simply saying **"WiFi: 802.11ac"**.

Until today, all devices I have ever found that supported 802.11ac also explicitly supported 802.11n. Therefore, I am guessing that this laptop vendor simply "summarized it".

**Does working with 802.11ac imply that it works with 802.11n as well?**

Or put in another way: **Is it possible for a device to work only with 802.11ac and not with 802.11n?**

---

EDIT: The specific laptop I'm talking about is Lenovo 80YH0006BR. I'm from Brazil, I'm afraid all useful links I found are in portuguese. Anyway, some links are [here](https://www3.lenovo.com/br/pt/laptops/ideapad/serie-300/Lenovo-IdeaPad-320-15IKB/p/80YH0006BR), [here](https://www.magazineluiza.com.br/notebook-lenovo-ideapad-320-intel-core-i5-8gb-1-tb-led-156-windows-10/p/2183136/in/note/) and [here](https://www.walmart.com.br/notebook-lenovo-intel-core-i5-8gb-1tb-ideapad-320-156-80yh0006br-windows-10-prata/5889726/pr?utm_source=buscape&utm_medium=xml_Buscape&utm_campaign=Buscape&tkSource=buscape&tkOffer=1c90e9b4-40d8-4ee1-9644-da94a4ad4959&dLog=20171105030818) (scroll down to find technical information).

Comment: "Can I trust that such laptop works with 802.11n?" No, unless it says so.

Comment: They're rare, but there are b/g/ac-only wifi adapters out there.

Comment: It is *super* unlikely it won’t support earlier standards.

Comment: @DanielB - That's what I was thinking, but wanted to make sure... When DavidPostill puts it that way, it makes me a bit worried though.

Comment: Do you have a link so we can investigate further?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I've edited the question with some links. Unfortunately, everything is in portuguese...

Comment: "Wifi A/C" Oh Lenovo, never stop amusing us...

Comment: According the this lenovo page [How to determine WiFi adapter type](https://support.lenovo.com/gb/en/solutions/ht103062) - "The newest generation of Wi-Fi signaling in popular use, 802.11ac, utilizes dual band wireless technology, supporting simultaneous connections on both the 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz Wi-Fi bands. 802.11ac offers backward compatibility to 802.11b/g/n. "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wifi cards that are available for the ideapad 320 according to its [Hardware Maintenance Manual](https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/ideapad320-15isk_320x-15isk_320-15ikb_320x-15ikb_320-15ikbtouch_hmm_201704.pdf) are:

- [Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/product-briefs/dual-band-wireless-ac-3165-brief.pdf)
- [Realtek RTL8821AE](http://www.realtek.com/products/productsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=21&PFid=60&Level=5&Conn=4&ProdID=387)
- [Qualcomm QCA9377](https://www.qualcomm.com/products/qca9377)

All three of these cards support 802.11a/b/g/n/ac wifi.

Answer (score 1):

The Lenovo 80YH0006BR laptop's wireless adapter is 100% compatible with 802.11n, as well as 802.11ac - The adapter would most likely be a Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377-5 or a variant of.

Comment: That's relieving!! But how do you know this? Can you add a source? :)

Comment: https://meraki.cisco.com/blog/2013/08/4-things-you-need-to-know-about-802-11ac/ - read the part about backwards compatibility - about a page down